# bold or higlight first row and column of tabe created from csv file

Tags: pgfplotstable, datatool, booktabs, csvsimple

I'm using `csvreader` from `csvsimple` package to read csv data and create table from it. My goal is to bold or somehow highlight first row and first column. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace} % REQUIRED BY \singlespacing
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}

% \usepackage{filecontents}
% \usepackage{datatool}
% \usepackage{booktabs}

% Make csv in question
\begin{filecontents*}{matrix.csv}
;a01;a02;a03;a04;a05;b01;b02;b03;b04;b05;b06
a01;0;147632;181326;199650;271006;197441;215211;291227;131358;126435;268400
a02;147632;0;456;145466;259520;136489;165306;768;174075;160202;256612
a03;271006;259520;0;249326;0;249935;249608;241720;326917;292472;263386
a04;7;119114;0;0;246267;133549;263651;258427;6;193472;251168
a05;199650;145466;256502;0;0;135343;131358;259080;234963;250919;343499
b01;197441;6;133549;763;249935;0;162260;259712;233051;678;251516
b02;215211;165306;148099;6;249608;162260;0;256502;253780;228519;245948
b03;256612;270029;258427;6;241720;259712;256502;0;343499;308085;263651
b04;131358;8;215073;54;326917;233051;253780;0;0;678;313316
b05;126435;160202;193472;211280;292472;209561;228519;0;0;0;283208
b06;268400;256612;251168;6;263386;251516;245948;263651;256502;283208;0

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \singlespacing
  \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
      \hline
      \csvreader[separator = semicolon,
                 column count=12,
                 no head,
                 table head=\hline,
                 late after line=\\\hline,
      ]
      {./matrix.csv}{
          1=\one, 2=\two, 3=\three, 4=\four,
          5=\five, 6=\six, 7=\seven, 8=\eight,
          9=\nine, 10=\ten, 11=\eleven, 12=\twelve
      }
      {\one & \two & \three & \four & \five & \six & \seven & \eight & \nine & \ten & \eleven & \twelve}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{adjustbox}
  \caption{TestTableA}
  \label{tab:TestTableA}
  \doublespacing
\end{table}

Results are contained in ~\ref{tab:TestTableA} table

\end{document}
```

I've tried also replace `table head=\hline,` with `table head = \hline \textbf{ rc } & \textbf{ a01 } & \textbf{ a02 } & \textbf{ a03 } & \textbf{ a04 } & \textbf{ a05 } & \textbf{ b01 } & \textbf{ b02 } & \textbf{ b03 } & \textbf{ b04 } & \textbf{ b05 } & \textbf{ b06 } \\\hline,` based on suggestions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82218/display-top-border-of-table-using-csvreader) but it gives me an error (another drawback is that the code looks ugly).

PS: I'm not strictly limited to `csvsimple` seems that [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175395/how-can-csv-files-be-put-into-latex-without-having-to-adjust-much) are several interesting packages that might do the job.

PPS: Is it possible to get rid somehow of those `1=\one, 2=\two, 3=\three ...` and `\one & \two & \three ....` and simply read the table as it is without specifying the columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is using `pgfplotstable` and a slightly modified version of the code in [PGFPlotsTable formatting problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276395/pgfplotstable-formatting-problems).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{adjustbox}


% Make csv in question
\begin{filecontents*}{matrix.csv}
;a01;a02;a03;a04;a05;b01;b02;b03;b04;b05;b06
a01;0;147632;181326;199650;271006;197441;215211;291227;131358;126435;268400
a02;147632;0;456;145466;259520;136489;165306;768;174075;160202;256612
a03;271006;259520;0;249326;0;249935;249608;241720;326917;292472;263386
a04;7;119114;0;0;246267;133549;263651;258427;6;193472;251168
a05;199650;145466;256502;0;0;135343;131358;259080;234963;250919;343499
b01;197441;6;133549;763;249935;0;162260;259712;233051;678;251516
b02;215211;165306;148099;6;249608;162260;0;256502;253780;228519;245948
b03;256612;270029;258427;6;241720;259712;256502;0;343499;308085;263651
b04;131358;8;215073;54;326917;233051;253780;0;0;678;313316
b05;126435;160202;193472;211280;292472;209561;228519;0;0;0;283208
b06;268400;256612;251168;6;263386;251516;245948;263651;256502;283208;0
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{matrix.csv}\WakanData
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
   \pgfplotstabletypeset[
     string type,
     every first column/.style={
        postproc cell  content/.append style={
            @cell content/.add={\bfseries}{}
        },
       column name={},
       column type/.add={|}{} % remove this to remove first vertical line
     },
     assign column name/.style={%
        /pgfplots/table/column name={\textbf{#1}}%
    },
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\hline}, % remove this and the next two lines to remove horizontal rules
    every odd row/.style={after row=\hline}, % horizontal rules
    every even row/.style={after row=\hline}, % horizontal rules
    column type/.add={}{|} % remove this to remove remaining vertical lines
    ]{\WakanData}
  \end{adjustbox}
  \caption{TestTableA}
  \label{tab:TestTableA}
\end{table}


Results are contained in ~\ref{tab:TestTableA} table

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you, it is also possible contain `tabulars` somehow (`\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}`)?

Comment: @WakanTanka Not sure what you mean. `\pgfplotstabletypeset` creates a `tabular` environment, you just don't see it. Do you just want add vertical lines between all the columns? Horizontal lines as well?

Comment: exactly, I want to add horizontal and vertical lines.

Comment: @WakanTanka Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you, if anyone wants version without horizontal/vertical lines here it is http://pastebin.com/0VJVRud7

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is make a data table in R and export to LaTeX with `xtable` (all within main document with **[knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/)**):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
<<table,echo=F,results='asis'>>=
library(xtable)
table <- read.csv2("matrix.csv")
rownames(table) <- table[,1]
bold <- function(x) {paste('{\\textbf{',x,'}}', sep ='')}
print(xtable(table[,1:12]),     
      sanitize.rownames.function=bold, 
      sanitize.colnames.function=bold, 
      booktabs=T, size="tiny",
      )
@
\end{document}
```

**Note**: to make vertical lines, you can specify  some option  like `align="|r|r|..."` in `xtable` function and remove the booktabs option in `print` function. But seriously, do not do that!